# Change field property in c#

Tags: c#, properties

Hi I have a class textProgreesBar which contains

```
public enum ProgressBarDisplayMode
{
    NoText,
    Percentage,
    CurrProgress,
    CustomText,
    TextAndPercentage,
    TextAndCurrProgress
}
```

Then

```
private ProgressBarDisplayMode _visualMode = ProgressBarDisplayMode.CurrProgress;
[Category("Additional Options"), Browsable(true)]
public ProgressBarDisplayMode VisualMode {
    get {
        return _visualMode;
    }
    set
    {
        _visualMode = value;
        Invalidate();//redraw component after change value from VS Properties section
    }
}
```

I try to dynamic change CurrProgress to Percentage on button click

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.textProgressBar1.VisualMode = "Percentage";
 }
```

But it quits with CS0029

Can I change this property on button click and how to do it?

Comment: you can do this `this.textProgressBar1.VisualMode = ProgressBarDisplayMode.Percentage;`

Comment: You need to use the enum value, try: `textProgressBar1.VisualMode = ProgressBarDisplayMode.Percentage;` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this.

```
this.textProgressBar1.VisualMode = ProgressBarDisplayMode.Percentage;
```

Comment: As ProgressBarDisplayMode is other Namespace  this.textProgressBar1.VisualMode = ProgressBarSample.ProgressBarDisplayMode.Percentage;. Thank you!

Comment: you can add the namespace with `using`